# Setting image of ImageButton by parsing xml

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I am working on android. I have an xml file and I am parsing xml to get data.

```
res/drawable/icon.png
```

I want to set button image path on the xml.Is there any way doing it other than calling it `R.drawable.icon` because i need many image buttons to insert my layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working on something similar these days, for a custom keyboard. In my case I'm using the images on the Assets folder, because I want to have the option of new Themes. In any case, you can create set the image from a bitmap. You better use ImageView instead of Button, and then you can set the image like this if loading from Assest:

```
setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open(filePath)));
```

Or this, if loading from resources:

```
image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(R.drawable.icon, null);
```

Comment: I have another question can you please help me ? Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175603/android-xml-parser-creating-spinner