# Android XML Parser - Creating Spinner

Tags: android, xml, arrays, spinner, items

Hi i am parsing xml file to insert buttons,textview and for creating them i am calling a function for each so that it may create many, depending on the xml. Now, i like to create a spinner in that xml. But i want to insert its items from an array.

```
<item>
<id>1</id>
<text>text1</text>
</item>
</items>
```

i dont want to enter the text in this way. i want to call an array.So what do i need to do?
how i am going to record array name into xml and call it? Can somebody please help me ?

Comment: Did you try to set `Adapter` on that spinner ?

Comment: yes i did in that way and it worked thanks

Comment: I've added an answer on my comment. Mark it accept if it was helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set Adapter on that spinner ? Like this :

```
Spinner spinner = ...;
final String[] choices = {"1","2"};

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(ObservationSubmit.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, choices);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner.setAdapter(a);
```